# How to POST checkbox values to array?

Tags: php

With the following I have a list of checkboxes:

```
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php
            $categories = get_categories(
                array( 'parent' => 184, 'hide_empty' => 0 )
            );
            foreach($categories as $c){
                $cat = get_category( $c );
                echo "<input type='checkbox' value=".$cat->cat_ID."> ".$cat->name."<br>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <input id="changeTema" name="changeTema" type="submit" value="AGGIORNA TEMA" class="btn secondary-btn primary-bg">
</form>
```

And when I submit, I am updating the DB

```
if ('AGGIORNA TEMA' === ($_POST['changeTema'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['changeTema'])) {
        wp_set_post_categories( $id, array(), FALSE );
    }
}
```

How can I add to `array()` the selected checkboxes in `wp_set_post_categories( $id, array(), FALSE );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the name as input arrays -

```
<input type='checkbox' name="sample[]" value=".$cat->cat_ID.">
```

And the code would be -

```
 $arr = $_POST['sample'];
 wp_set_post_categories( $id, $arr, FALSE );
```

Comment: ok thank you, any specific reason why we're setting it as a var and not simply doing `wp_set_post_categories( $id, $_POST['sample'];, FALSE );` ?